# Trying to hide images in html email - not working in Outlook 2010

Tags: html, image, email, outlook, hide

I'm building device-responsive emails for mobile. As part of this I want some images that appear on desktop/webmail to be hidden on mobile and vice versa.

I've got it working on all web clients, and mobile devices that I've tested, but Outlook shows all images in the file.

I've tried combinations of **display:none;**, **visibility; hidden** and **width="0"** on images, tds, tables and tried with divs as well.

I know there's a workaround with using background images instead, but it's not ideal as some of the images are acting as buttons and need links behind them.

Would appreciate any help,

Thanks.

Sharon

Comment: Couldn't figure it out for you. But I found this resource: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx  weird note: "display" is on both the supported and un-supported CSS properties lists

Comment: As far as a workaround with bg images, Outlook 2007/2010/2013 doesn't support bg images (except on the body tag, and even then it doesn't scale consistently with other browsers).

Comment: The problem might not be a matter of whether a particular CSS style works in Outlook, but of how you're trying to apply it (external style sheet vs internal style sheet vs inline styles) and whether it's in a media query. Showing the relevant code for how the CSS is applied would be helpful. Bear in mind that Outlook 2007 and up renders emails using the rendering engine of Word rather than IE, so much of what works in web browsers will not work in Outlook.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I've now managed to fix it. I think what Matt was saying was right; My problem WAS to do with inline styles.

Comment: And, just as a note - I used the background images on a div previously which worked in Outlook, just had problems with getting a link to work behind it. But prefer to use 'real' images, and now have got that sorted... onto the issues with floating...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies, I've now managed to fix it. I think what Matt was saying was right; My problem WAS to do with inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue whereby I wanted two different size images and wanted them both to be clickable as a link.

My media query is only targeting mobile devices, so I can define the height of the containing table cell and ensure that the link is a set block height.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px) {      
td[class="image-class"], 
a[class="image-link-class"]{
height:165px!important; 
display: block; !important};
img[class="desktop-content"]{
display: none !important; 
height:0 !important; 
min-height: 0 !important; 
max-height: 0 !important; width:0 !important; overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

The image then has a class which bazookas's everything into 0 to ensure it really is hidden. For desktop based email clients the background image of the table cell is never seen and is then covered by the inline image

```
<td height="473" background="image-mobile.jpg" class="image-class"><a href="#" class="image-link-class"><img src="image-desktop.jpg" width="318" height="473" border="0" alt="" style="display:block" class="desktop-content"></a></td>
```